# Are the following boundaries correct.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am attempting to understand boundaries. I am trying to use the following definition:

$Bd(A) = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^{\complement}}$

to find out the boundries of the sequence 1/n and of the set (1,4].

I believe the Bd({1/n})={0} and Bd((1,4]) = {1 , 4}.

Am I correct?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you believe that $Bd(\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n=1,2,\dots\}=\{0\}$? Is e.g. $\frac{1}{2}$ not an element of the closure of $A^c$ where $A=\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n=1,2,\dots\}$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}$ would the set from 0 to 1 not including 0 right? So $A^c$ would include zero. I don't see how the closure of $A^c$ would include 1/2. Since it wouldn't have the numbers from 0 to 1 in it?

Comment: See my answer and check wether we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: In which topological space are you working? In $\mathbb R$? Then the closure of $A^c$ is $\mathbb R$

Comment: Your answer makes sense. Thank you! and yes, working in the reals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n=1,2,\dots\}\subset\mathbb R$ then $\overline A=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n=1,2,\dots\}$ and $\overline{A^c}=\mathbb R$

So: $$\partial A:=\overline A\cap\overline{A^c}=\cdots$$

---

In general $x\in\partial A$ iff each open set $U$ with $x\in U$ has non-empty intersections with $A$ and $A^c$.

Working in $\mathbb R$ you can weaken this by saying that each open interval $(a,b)$ with $a<x<b$ must have non-empty intersections with $A$ and $A^c$.

Example: let $(a,b)$ be an open interval with $a<\frac{1}{2}<b$. Then  $A\cap (a,b)\neq\emptyset$ and also $A^c\cap (a,b)\neq\emptyset$, hence $\frac{1}{2}\in\partial A$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are working in $\mathbb{R}$.

You are right in saying that the boundary of $A=(1,4]$ is $\{1,4\}$.

For the first set, $A=\left\{ \frac{1}{n} \right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$, you need to be more careful. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$. Then $\frac{1}{k} \in A$, so clearly $\frac{1}{k} \notin A^c$. However, you can find an open neighbourhood around $\frac{1}{k}$, say $(a,b)$, such that $\left( (a,b)\setminus \left\{ \frac{1}{k} \right\} \right) \cap A = \varnothing$. In other words, $(a,b)\setminus \left\{\frac{1}{k} \right\} \subset A^c$. Then just pick a sequence in this punctured interval which tends to $\frac{1}{k}$. By construction, each term of this sequence lies in $A^c$, so by definition $\frac{1}{k} \in \overline{A^c}$. Clearly $\frac{1}{k} \in \overline{A}$, so $\frac{1}{k} \in \operatorname{Bd}(A)$. As you noted, $0$ is also in the boundary of $A$, so we have: $\operatorname{Bd}(A)=A \cup \{0\}$.